# Android create programmatically a new Calendar?

Tags: android

How can I programmatically create a new Calendar in Android?

Comment: in Google Calendar? If so you'll need to use the Google Calendar API, this is not possible with just the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: Most likely the OP wants to create a Calender widget, not a java.util.Calendar object

Comment: Fuzzy question => Fuzzy answer